# Traspuesta de matriz formada por QueueOfStacks (Java)

Tags: java, matrices, queue, stack

buenas. Tengo un ejercicio de la facultad que me esta costando hacer. Este consiste trasponer una matriz formada por una Cola de Pilas. En la implementacion tanto de QueueOfStacks, como de Stack cuento con los metodos: *add, remove, isEmpty, getFirst (o getTop)*. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?...

Comment: En como podria hacer para poder trasponer este QueueOfStacks

Comment: Hola p3p1, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Hola, como estas? Entiendo lo que decis, soy nuevo en esta comunidad y no sabia como hacer la pregunta. Tampoco tenia el codigo que habia probado conmigo en ese momento. Por suerte ya lo pude resolver y muchas gracias por la amabilidad. Dejo la resolución en la pregunta por si alguien tiene la misma duda!

Answer (score 1):

Pude encontrar la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien!

```
public static QueueOfStacks Transpose(QueueOfStacks queue) {
    QueueOfStacks transposeQueue = new QueueOfStacks();

    int stackSize = queue.getFirst().size();
    int queueSize = queue.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++) {
        Stack transposeStack = new Stack();
        for (int j = 0; j < queueSize; j++) {
            Stack currentStack = queue.getFirst();
            int candidate = currentStack.getTop();
            transposeStack.add(candidate);
            currentStack.remove();
            queue.add(currentStack);
            queue.remove();
        }
        transposeQueue.add(transposeStack);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++) {
        Stack finalStack = new Stack();
        for (int j = 0; j < stackSize; j++) {
            finalStack.add(transposeQueue.getFirst().getTop());
            transposeQueue.getFirst().remove();
        }
        transposeQueue.add(finalStack);
        transposeQueue.remove();
    }
    return transposeQueue;
}
```

Comment: Hola de nuevo, gracias por tomarte el trabajo de compartir la solución que encontraste, pocos lo hacen, ahora bien, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.